# Pull data from database on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I was wondering whether it is possible in JavaScript (preferably jQuery) to pull data from a database using MySQL after clicking on a button? I currently pull data when the page loads, but I don't want to load 100's of items at the beginning as I want to be able to pull certain rows with different buttons?

Comment: Is it possible to get specific rows with AJAX, or does it just pull the table?

Comment: Not without server-side code, no.

Comment: You can if you use a server side language like PHP between your javascript and MySQL database. But you already have that I guess as you state you are able to show data on page load. So yea I guess -> AJAX

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You'd either post some form which would return the updated page (a page reload) or you'd request the data in the background from client-side code and add it to the page (AJAX).  As it stands this question is a bit broad.  We'll be happy to help with any problems you encounter while developing this, but "is it possible" questions are generally either answered with simply a "yes" or "no".

Comment: I don't want the page to reload after pulling from the database, so AJAX is the best option? Martijn below suggested `$.get()`

Comment: `$.get()` is a jQuery AJAX function.

Comment: @j08691 I'd prefer using `$.get()` as it seems consistent with my `$.post()` method. Is there a difference performance-wise? Sorry for the noobish questions

Comment: Made an edit with some documentation when to get/post. Simply punt: Will calling the url with parameters *change* your database? In case it just gets content, use GET. Does it delete/insert/update? Then POST.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="AjaxTrigger" data-example="abc">I do ABC </button>

$('.AjaxTrigger').on('click', function(){
    $.get("your-file.php", {example: $(this).data('example')}, function(result){
        alert( "This is what php gave me: " + "\n" +result );
    }
});
```

And now you let `your-file.php` do whatever you want, just like you normaly program you php files. Echo the outcome, and in javascript you will get exactly that in the returnfunction (which now alerts your result).

- [jQuery's full ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or [jQuery's get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) (works easier)
- [Using jQuery to access data-* attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [jQuery's eventhandling explained](http://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/) (event are eg: click, hover, keyup)
- [When to use GET or POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get) (<- Good to read for everyone)

And if you feel like upping your game:

- [Use jQuery's getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to send back an array to javascript ( echo with php's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode))